# How can I stop IE from caching an unauthenticated redirect?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, redirect, web-config, http-caching

My application is configured to redirect to the login page on authentication errors:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
          <remove statusCode="401" />
          <error statusCode="401" responseMode="Redirect" path="/Login" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
<configuration>
```

This produces a 302 redirect instead of a 401, and the user is taken to the login page.  On most browsers, that works fine.  On IE (both 10 and 11, the only versions we support), we are sometimes seeing that this redirect gets cached, so this happens:

- Not-logged-in user navigates to `/`
- Unauthenticated request is 302-redirected to `/Login`
- User successfully enters credentials
- Login page directs user to `/`
- IE remembers that the last time it navigated to `/`, it received a 302 response, so it doesn't even bother sending another request to the server, and instantly loops back to `/Login` instead

The main application is MVC5, so I tried adding an IE-only filter that would force it to not cache.  For example:

```
public class InternetExplorerNoCacheFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (RequestBrowserIsInternetExplorer)
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
    }
}
```

It performs as expected on normal pages.  But unfortunately, the web.config authentication redirect happens earlier in the pipeline, so my filter isn't getting called for the unauthenticated request, which is where I need it the most.

I don't want to set a universal no-cache header, because other browsers cache responsibly, and it improves performance for them.

How can I selectively prevent IE from caching the unauthenticated redirect to the Login page?